# Can't get my TextView to update in a fragment

Tags: android, android-layout, android-fragments, textview

I have tried everything I can possibly think of, I have tried many solutions in Stack as well. None seem to resolve my issue. I am trying to pass a string that I passed from an earlier intent (parsed JSON data). Everytime I call set text I get a Null Pointer Exception, I have tried using a method to set the text as well as just setting it. Any assistance would be greatly appreciated.

This is the fragment I am trying to update.

```
public class HomeFragment extends Fragment{
TextView tv;
public HomeFragment(){}


@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
        Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    LayoutInflater lf = getActivity().getLayoutInflater();

    View rootView = lf.inflate(R.layout.fragment_home, container, false);
    tv  = (TextView) rootView.findViewById(R.id.accountName);
    tv.setText("test");
    return rootView;
}

}
```

I just put a regular string in to test. Here is the XML.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent">


<TextView
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge"
    android:text="Large Text"
    android:id="@+id/lblCompany"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    android:layout_marginTop="71dp" />
</RelativeLayout>
```

Thanks In advance for absolutely any help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is the id set on your `TextView` in xml:

```
android:id="@+id/lblCompany"
```

This is the id you are searching for in `onCreateView`:

```
tv = (TextView) rootView.findViewById(R.id.accountName);
```

The ids need to match for you to update the text in that particular `TextView`. Try

```
tv = (TextView) rootView.findViewById(R.id.lblCompany);
```

instead.